# Use Automator for handling multiple file inputs through shell command in OS X

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, automator

I tried to make an Automator drag and drop application but I'm totally lost. The script should use `cat` to join multiple audio files together.

Steps:

1. Read the selected finder files (which I drop on the application) .
2. Execute the shell command "cat" with the file names. e.g. "cat 1.m4a 2.m4a > joined.m4a"
3. The output filename should be set before by a "Save As" window.

Comment: Beside the main point, but can you really just `cat` audio files together? I didn't know that...

Answer (score 4):

Note: Asking for the output filename is not implemented in this solution. It's hard coded in the script.

1. Open Automator
2. Drag and drop the `Get Selected Finder Items` action from the library (under `Files & Folders`)
3. Drag and drop the `Run Shell Script` action from the library (under `Utilities`)
4. In the `Pass Input:` dropdown, choose "as arguments"
5. In the textbox below, type the shell script (which is by default populated with a script to echo all the filenames), like for example,

   > for f in "$@"
   >   do
   >   cat "$f" > joined.m4a
   >   done
6. From the `File` menu, save this as an app
7. Drag and drop multiple files on to the app to run the script on those files